# Error 'getStaticPaths can only be used with dynamic pages, not '/'' with Next JS

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

I want to use getStaticPaths for my posts blog with dynamic routes but I get an error while building.

**My folder with dynamic routes :**

pages/articles/[category]/[slug].js

**My Link Navigation:**

```
    <Link href={`/article/${category}/${slug}`} passHref>
      <Card>
        ...some data
      </Card>
    <Link />
```

**My getStaticPaths:**

```js
export async function getStaticPaths () {
   
  // retrieve data from cms

  const data = await getAllPreviewPosts()

  // generate the paths

  const paths = data.map( ({ fields: { slug , stackName } }) => ({ 
   params: { category: stackName, slug: slug } 
   }))

  return {
     paths, 
     fallback: false
  }   
}

export async function getStaticProps () {
 /* ... get data from cms */
}
```

But when I run `npm run build` I get this error:

```
Error: getStaticPaths can only be used with dynamic pages, not '/'.
```

Comment: In which file is `getStaticPaths` ?

Answer (score 3):

[`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) defines which pages next.js has to render when exporting. It is used to generate all available dynamic routes. You cannot use that data on the page itself.

To get all available categories and slugs to use it in your navigation component, you need to use [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) to load the data on the page and pass it into your navigation component as props.

You can find an example for this here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-static-export/pages/index.js

Answer (score 2):

It seems the url for [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) has changed somewhat. Your folder with dynamic routes should be perhaps:

```
pages/articles/[category]/[[slug]].js
```

and not:

```
pages/articles/[category]/[slug].js
```

The difference between [Catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes) and [Optional catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) is explained [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Given a file structure such as :

```
pages
│   ├── 404.js
│   ├── 500.js
│   ├── _app.js
│   └── store
│       └── [[...slug]].js
```

The following getStaticPaths fnct should cover all these routes:

```
/store
/store/portfolio
/store/design-system
/store/cart

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { slug: [''] } }, // <-- Get the data on the page itself
      { params: { slug: ['portfolio'] } },
      { params: { slug: ['design-system'] } },
      { params: { slug: ['cart'] } },
    ],
    fallback: false
  }
}
```